# Members inaccessible with friend function

Tags: c++

I am getting an error that I cannot explain. Here is my header file:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
namespace project
{
#ifndef MATRIX_H
#define MATRIX_H

typedef int* IntArrayPtr;
class Matrix
{
public:
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Matrix& object);
    friend istream& operator>>(istream& in, Matrix& theArray);
    //Default Constructor
    Matrix();

    Matrix(int max_number_rows, int max_number_cols, int intial_value);

    //Destructor
    ~Matrix();
    //Copy Constructor
    Matrix(const Matrix& right_side);
    //Assignment Operator
    Matrix& operator=(const Matrix& right_side);

    void Clear();
    int Rows();
    int Columns();
    bool GetCell(int x,int y, int& val);
    bool SetCell(int x,int y, int val);
    //void Debug(ostream& out);
private:
    int initialVal;
    int rows;
    int cols;
    IntArrayPtr *m;
};
#endif
}
```

And here my definition:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Matrix& object)
{
    for(int r = 0; r < object.rows; r++)
    {
        for(int c = 0; c < object.cols; c++)
        {
            out << object.m[r][c] << " ";
        }
        out << endl;
    }
    return out;
}
```

It's giving me the error that Matrix.h members are inaccessible, but I clearly stated that they are friend function.

Comment: I bet you this is because you did not put the implementation in the same namespace as the class in your header.

Comment: Is that definition inside the class?

Answer (score 2):

Where are those function definitions located? The `friend` declaration injects the names into `namespace project`. If the functions aren't defined in that namespace, they're different functions and not friends.

Comment: It's defined in my implementation file matrix.cpp.  I've included in the implementation file by stating "using namespace project;".

Comment: `using namespace project` is **not** the same as defining the functions **inside** the namespace. You have to wrap those definitions inside `namespace project { ... }`.

Answer (score 1):

Your function implementation should also reside in the `project` namespace - just declaring that you are using it is not enough, the function itself is 'global' if you don't specify it as such and then won't be able to access the members since it is friended in the wrong namespace scope.

[Compiles fine with this fix](https://eval.in/80434).

[Does not compile otherwise](https://eval.in/80433).

Answer (score 0):

Try to define your two friend functions outside your Matrix class.

Like :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
namespace project
{
#ifndef MATRIX_H
#define MATRIX_H

typedef int* IntArrayPtr;
class Matrix
{
public:
    //Default Constructor
    Matrix();

    Matrix(int max_number_rows, int max_number_cols, int intial_value);

    //Destructor
    ~Matrix();
    //Copy Constructor
    Matrix(const Matrix& right_side);
    //Assignment Operator
    Matrix& operator=(const Matrix& right_side);

    void Clear();
    int Rows();
    int Columns();
    bool GetCell(int x,int y, int& val);
    bool SetCell(int x,int y, int val);
    //void Debug(ostream& out);
private:
    int initialVal;
    int rows;
    int cols;
    IntArrayPtr *m;
};
 ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Matrix& object);
 istream& operator>>(istream& in, Matrix& theArray);

#endif
}
```