# C++: Member is inaccessible - using friend function to allow one class to modify another class member data

Tags: c++, friend

Okay, I have looked all over for an answer to this.

I am trying to set up a system where an object's private members can be modified only through two member functions of a separate class.

Here is the header content of the object to be modified, table.h:

```
#ifndef TABLE_H
#define TABLE_H

#include "party.h"

/*
Seats a party for their dining experience at the restaurant.
*/
class table
{
    friend void server::seatGuests(const table &, const party &);
    friend void server::cleanTable(const table &);

private:
    const unsigned int cap_; //guest capacity (shouldn't change)
    const unsigned int id_;  //table id (shouldn't change)
    mutable bool isTaken_;   //flag (changeable by friend functions)
    party *const group_;     //party seated at the table (starts off as null)

public:
    table::table(const unsigned int id, const unsigned int cap = 4); //ctor
    inline const unsigned int table::getCap() const { return cap_; }
    inline const unsigned int table::getId() const { return id_; }
    inline const bool table::isTaken() const { return isTaken_; }
    inline const party *const table::getParty() const { return group_; };
};

void server::seatGuests(const table &t, const party &p)
{
    t.isTaken_ = false;
}

#endif // TABLE_H
```

here is server.h:

```
class server : public employee
{
private:
public:
    explicit server::server();
    void server::seatGuests(const table &, const party &);
    void server::cleanTable(const table &);
};

...
```

I am getting the following error:
`member "table::isTaken_" (declared at line 17) is inaccessible`

The server.h file is included in table.h indirectly, as party.h includes restaurant.h which includes server.h.

I tried putting this in table.h before:

```
class server;
namespace server {
   void server::seatGuests(const table &, const party &);
   void server::cleanTable(const table &);
}
```

But this just gave me more headaches, as the compiler would spit out something like, "class server has no member 'seatGuests' or 'cleanTable'", which I figured was due to some inclusion conflict. This conflict is why I've declared the function in the original server.h file and not in the table.h file.

That being said, sources I've read such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20643758/members-inaccessible-with-friend-function) state that the implementation of the friend function should be in the class whose data is being modified, which is what I've done.

All that aside, the compiler still thinks the member data is not accessible. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong here?

Let me know if you want me to post more code.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

Apologies for the delay in posting the compiler output. Please see below:

```
> Executing task: clang++ -Wall -std=c++17 -stdlib=libc++ -o main.out /Users/ajm/Projects/restaurant/cpp/main/main.cpp -I/Users/ajm/Projects/restaurant/cpp/main/ -I/Users/ajm/Projects/restaurant/cpp/restaurant/ -I/Users/ajm/Projects/restaurant/cpp/people/ -I/Users/ajm/Projects/restaurant/cpp/people/workers/ -I/Users/ajm/Projects/restaurant/cpp/data/ --debug <

In file included from /Users/ajm/Projects/restaurant/cpp/main/main.cpp:1:
In file included from /Users/ajm/Projects/restaurant/cpp/main/simulation.h:4:
In file included from /Users/ajm/Projects/restaurant/cpp/restaurant/restaurant.h:4:
In file included from /Users/ajm/Projects/restaurant/cpp/restaurant/tablespace.h:4:
In file included from /Users/ajm/Projects/restaurant/cpp/restaurant/table.h:4:
In file included from /Users/ajm/Projects/restaurant/cpp/people/workers/server.h:4:
In file included from /Users/ajm/Projects/restaurant/cpp/people/workers/employee.h:5:
In file included from /Users/ajm/Projects/restaurant/cpp/main/../data/job.h:4:
/Users/ajm/Projects/restaurant/cpp/people/party.h:25:16: error: unknown type name 'restaurant'
    void start(restaurant &spot);
               ^
In file included from /Users/ajm/Projects/restaurant/cpp/main/main.cpp:1:
In file included from /Users/ajm/Projects/restaurant/cpp/main/simulation.h:4:
In file included from /Users/ajm/Projects/restaurant/cpp/restaurant/restaurant.h:4:
In file included from /Users/ajm/Projects/restaurant/cpp/restaurant/tablespace.h:4:
/Users/ajm/Projects/restaurant/cpp/restaurant/table.h:8:11: error: redefinition of 'server' as different kind of
      symbol
namespace server
          ^
/Users/ajm/Projects/restaurant/cpp/restaurant/table.h:7:7: note: previous definition is here
class server;
      ^
/Users/ajm/Projects/restaurant/cpp/restaurant/table.h:10:23: error: unknown type name 'table'
void seatGuests(const table &t, const party *const p);
                      ^
/Users/ajm/Projects/restaurant/cpp/restaurant/table.h:11:23: error: unknown type name 'table'
void cleanTable(const table &t);
                      ^
/Users/ajm/Projects/restaurant/cpp/restaurant/table.h:13:31: error: unknown type name 'table'
void server::seatGuests(const table &t, const party *const p)
                              ^
/Users/ajm/Projects/restaurant/cpp/restaurant/table.h:18:31: error: unknown type name 'table'
void server::cleanTable(const table &t)
                              ^
/Users/ajm/Projects/restaurant/cpp/restaurant/table.h:42:25: error: out-of-line declaration of 'seatGuests' does not
      match any declaration in 'server'
    friend void server::seatGuests(const table &t, const party *const p);
                        ^~~~~~~~~~
/Users/ajm/Projects/restaurant/cpp/restaurant/table.h:43:25: error: out-of-line declaration of 'cleanTable' does not
      match any declaration in 'server'
    friend void server::cleanTable(const table &t);
                        ^~~~~~~~~~
8 errors generated.
The terminal process terminated with exit code: 1
```

Comment: To start with, member declarations within a class declaration should not have a class qualifier. Fixing this may fix some of the error messages.

Comment: Secondly, I don’t think you can declare class member functions (without a body)  at namespace scope, as in your final excerpt.

Comment: Is class server in the namespace server? If so, the definition of seatGuests should be server::server::seatGuests.

Comment: If you can post a full (stripped-down) compilation unit that gives the error, I’m sure someone can give you an answer right away.

Comment: What compiler are you using? Do you have all warnings enabled? What is the first warning/error message the compiler produces?

Comment: @prl I've removed all the class qualifiers, thank you. As for declaring class member functions without a body at the namespace scope, you are probably correct. I'm going to do some digging to find the correct way to do this. And to answer your third question, it shouldn't be. I will remove the extra qualifiers.

Comment: @JaMiT I'm using clang++, and yes I have with -Wall. See the above compiler output to answer your third question. I'm going to keep digging through references in search of the correct way to do this.

Comment: Did you try including server before table? I mean put `#include "server.h"` above `table`.

Comment: Oh it looks like you might have cyclic includes

Comment: Does `server` include `table`? If it does then I think that's your problem

Comment: 1. You need to make sure they include one another. 2. You need to do forward declaration. Add `class server;` before `class table{...}`. 3. When you have such cyclic dependency, it's best to revise your design and try to come up with a better way to remove the cycle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The declaration of `server::seatGuests` and `server::cleanTable` must appear before the `friend` declaration in `table`. `#include "server.h"` appears before the declaration of `table` so that should be enough right? Well, `server` includes `table` and `table` includes `server` so we have cyclic dependencies. To get around this, `table` should include `server` and `server` should forward declare `table`.

```
// table.h

#include "party.h"

class table
{
    friend void server::seatGuests(const table &, const party &);
    friend void server::cleanTable(const table &);
};



// server.h

class table;
class party;

class server : public employee
{
public:
    explicit server();
    void seatGuests(const table &, const party &);
    void cleanTable(const table &);
};
```

Cyclic dependencies and friend declarations seem like bad design to me. Instead of using a forward declaration to get around this, you might want to rethink the design. Find a way to avoid the cycle and avoid the friend declarations. *My answer is a workaround, not a solution.*

Comment: Thank you. You are absolutely right about the design. I also think I need to step back and spend more time reading up on C++ to ensure I am using appropriate data types in member classes.